# Ortografía: por qué, porque, por que, porqué

Tags: discusión, idioma-español

Sé que nuestro sitio es sobre programación y no sobre ortografía y gramática, pero me gustaría llamar la atención sobre una incorrección ortográfica que veo a menudo en preguntas y respuestas: la confusión entre las cuatro formas disponibles de por+que (junto y separado, con y sin tilde). A continuación pongo un breve resumen sobre las normas de uso de dicha palabra, con la esperanza de que os sea útil.

- Para preguntar se usa **por qué**:

> ¿**Por qué** no puedo foobarizar un fizzbuzz?

- ...y para responder, **porque**:

> **Porque** la clase Fizzbuzz no implementa IFoobarizable.

- **Por que** es equivalente a *por el/la/lo cual*:

> La razón **por que** no puedes es simple: la clase Fizzbuzz no implementa IFoobarizable.

- **Porqué** es un sustantivo que significa "la razón", "la causa":

> El **porqué** de la imposibilidad de foobarizar un fizzbuzz hay que buscarlo en la definición de la clase.

Comment: Señor. Me disculpo y me añado a la lista de culpables desde ya.... soy un horror ortograficamente hablando....

Comment: Sería perfecto para un post en http://spanish.stackexchange.com/ :D

Comment: @Equiso: [Ya existe](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14/12), pero las respuestas no mencionan "por que".

Comment: @Flimzy ¡la [respuesta de Diego](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/13503/1674) sí!

Comment: ¡¡Ya era hora de que alguien lo dijera!!

Comment: Echaré un vistazo en la *Nueva gramática de la lengua española* (2009) para ver ***`qué`*** dice al respecto.

Answer (score 3):

No vendría mal aportar como respuesta lo que dice la RAE al respecto:

> #### a) porqué
>
> Es un sustantivo masculino que equivale a causa, motivo, razón, y se
> escribe con tilde por ser palabra aguda terminada en vocal. Puesto que
> se trata de un sustantivo, se usa normalmente precedido de artículo u
> otro determinante:
>
> *No comprendo **el porqué** de tu actitud* [= la razón de tu actitud].
>
> *Todo tiene **su porqué*** [= su causa o su motivo].
>
> Como otros sustantivos, tiene plural:
>
> *Hay que averiguar los **porqués** de este cambio de actitud.*
>
> ---
>
> #### b) por qué
>
> Se trata de la secuencia formada por la preposición por y el
> interrogativo o exclamativo qué (palabra tónica que se escribe con
> tilde diacrítica para distinguirla del relativo y de la conjunción
> que). Introduce oraciones interrogativas y exclamativas directas e
> indirectas:
>
> *¿**Por qué** no viniste ayer a la fiesta?*
>
> *No comprendo **por qué** te pones así.*
>
> *¡**Por qué** calles más bonitas pasamos!*
>
> Obsérvese que, a diferencia del sustantivo porqué, la secuencia por
> qué no puede sustituirse por términos como razón, causa o motivo.
>
> ---
>
> #### c) porque
>
> Se trata de una conjunción átona, razón por la que se escribe sin
> tilde. Puede usarse con dos valores:
>
> - Como conjunción causal, para introducir oraciones subordinadas que expresan causa, caso en que puede sustituirse por locuciones de valor
>   asimismo causal como puesto que o ya que:
>
> *No fui a la fiesta **porque** no tenía ganas* [= ya que no tenía ganas].
>
> *La ocupación no es total, **porque** quedan todavía plazas libres* [= puesto que quedan todavía plazas libres].
>
> También se emplea como encabezamiento de las respuestas a las
> preguntas introducidas por la secuencia por qué:
>
> —¿Por qué no viniste? —***Porque** no tenía ganas*.
>
> Cuando tiene sentido causal, es incorrecta su escritura en dos
> palabras.
>
> - Como conjunción final, seguida de un verbo en subjuntivo, con sentido equivalente a para que:
>
> *Hice cuanto pude **porque** no terminara así* [= para que no terminara así].
>
> En este caso, se admite también la grafía en dos palabras (pero se
> prefiere la escritura en una sola):
>
> *Hice cuanto pude por que no terminara así*.
>
> ---
>
> #### d) por que
>
> Puede tratarse de una de las siguientes secuencias:
>
> - La preposición por + el pronombre relativo que. En este caso es más corriente usar el relativo con artículo antepuesto (el que, la que,
>   etc.):
>
> *Este es el motivo **por** (el) **que** te llamé.*
>
> *Los premios **por** (los) **que** competían no resultaban muy atractivos.*
>
> *No sabemos la verdadera razón **por** (la) **que** dijo eso.*
>
> - La preposición por + la conjunción subordinante que. Esta secuencia aparece en el caso de verbos, sustantivos o adjetivos que rigen un
>   complemento introducido por la preposición por y llevan además una
>   oración subordinada introducida por la conjunción que:
>
> *Al final optaron **por que** no se presentase.*
>
> *Están ansiosos **por que** empecemos a trabajar en el proyecto.*
>
> *Nos confesó su preocupación **por que** los niños pudieran enfermar.*

---

Fuente: [Real Academia Española](http://www.rae.es/consultas/porque-porque-por-que-por-que)

---

**P. D.:** Si has leído y memorizado esto, no se entenderá el **porqué** no usas ¿**por qué ...**?  cuando planteas tus **porqués**.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro el motivo por que uso `porqué` en el primer `porqué` de  la post-data es porque estaba implementando el caso **a**.

Comment: No comprendiste porque era una afirmación, no una interrogación indirecta:  _no se entenderá el motivo = **`porqué`** de no usar ¿por qué? cuando planteas tus porqués_

Comment: Tienes razón @AlvaroMontoro, faltaba el artículo. Ver post-data editada.